# playing youtube videos inline with API3

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api, inline, youtube-data-api

i am building an ios app, and up until recently we were able to play youtube videos inline with no problems.

now with the latest API, we are having trouble getting the same result. it just returns this "device support" video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKY3scPIMd8

how can i play youtube videos inline? specifically videos related to WMG & VEVO, etc.
please let me know of any alternate solutions as well.
thank you